# How to detect the click on a button that is inside of a dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with a very simple thing. I have two buttons inside a dropdown, and I can't detect when the user click on them. The rest of the buttons works well, less this two.

The buttons are:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Nodes</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="NodeFilters">
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm' id='allFilter'>All</button>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm' id='cleanFilter'>Clean</button>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My function is:

```
//This function controls if some button is clicked
function btnController(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        let id_btn = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(id_btn);

        if(id_btn == 'allFilter' | id_btn == 'cleanFilter'){
            alert('sss')
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    btnController();
} );
```

When I click the rest of the buttons, the `console.log(id_btn);` prints the `id` of the button. But when I click these two buttons inside the dropdown, nothing happens. Why is this happening?

Note: When I click these buttons, the dropdown always gets closed.

Can somebody help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using bootstrap here?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov yess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation like this:

```
$(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
          let id_btn = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log(id_btn);

            if(id_btn === 'allFilter' || id_btn === 'cleanFilter'){
                alert('sss')
            }
        })
      })
```

Comment: Thank you! IT works, but I don't understand why? :S

Comment: @Lleims By the way your solution works on my machine as well. Anyway, if my solution helps, please don't forget to make green tick to my answer ;)

Comment: Yes I know it, but SO makes you wait a few minutes XD

Comment: For me no problem, at least my solution also helps you! Regards ;)

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov there is a typo in your `if` statement, `|` should be double pipe, `||` and you should use `===` instead of `==`